Angular Jasmine Unit Testing How To Handle CORS Policy Error
I'm  having an issue with CORS blocking on my unit test using Jasmine,  I understand the
issue but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have handle the CORS issue with my application on the backend everything is fine.
Issue Karma is on http://localhost:9876 and
Angular application is on http://localhost:4200
My unit test services are mocked so there is no real service being used
My application runs with no issues, its the unit testing that give me the error:
I using focus when running my test so there are only 9 test and 1 fails.
I know my product.service.spec completes because of console.log "result verified "
The product-item.componet.html is the culprit.
I know the issue is in my template. In my research I have found nothing related to my actual issue.  I did see something regarding the CLI but it was a different type of issue. Any point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Snippet:
product-item.component.html:
   <img class=" img-fluid shacker"  [src]="productItem.imageUrl" alt="Clothing" />

product Model:
 export class Product {
   _id:string;
   name: string;
   size: string;
   description: string;
   price: number;
   imageUrl: string;
   static price: Product;

   constructor(_id:string, name: string, description="", size:string, price=0, 
   imageUrl="" ){

    this._id=_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price= price;
    this.size= size;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

 }

karma.config.js
   module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
     basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
    require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
client: {
  clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
},
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
  dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/DivasandDollsChi'),
  reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
},
reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false,
restartOnFileChange: true

  });
};

package.json
{
"name": "divasand-dolls-chi",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"api": "json-server api/db.json --routes api/routes.json --no-cors=true"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/localize": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.5",
"@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.1",
"@paypal/paypal-js": "^5.1.0",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
"ajv": "^8.16.0",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"creditcardpayments": "^1.0.3",
"dotenv": "^16.0.1",
"i": "^0.3.7",
"interface": "^1.2.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"json-server": "^0.12.2",
"jw-angular-pagination": "^1.2.0",
"ng-img-magnifier": "^1.2.1",
"ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
"ngx-image-zoom": "^0.6.0",
"ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
"ngx-pinch-zoom": "^2.6.2",
"node-fetch": "^3.2.6",
"nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"pug": "^3.0.2",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"sequelize": "^6.6.2",
"sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.13.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/cli": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.5",
"@types/events": "^3.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"karma": "~6.4.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}


Please share your Karma.conf.js and your package.json
